# I need help with removing words or changing bulk slugs

Tags: functions, slug, code

Heres the best example.

1. urls are in a domain.com/locations
2. they say domain.com/locations/used-honda-cbr-goldwing-in-sarasota-fl
3. I need them to say: domain.com/locations/used-honda-cbr-in-sarasota-fl

I didnt know if postname is the same if I have several postnames.php (single.php)locations.php, etc.

Or should I just quick edit and remove them?